# create a text boxes for everty product in ruby on rails(shopify app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I have created an app using ruby on rails for Shopify.This time app is displaying available products on the store.

But I want text boxes for every product to display the text box values in the product page. So how can I achieve this? I have read somewhere that this can be done by `metafields` and I have used the below code:

In the controller:

```
@products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:limit => 10})
```

In the view:

```
<% @products.metafields.each do |metafield| %>
<%= metafield.key %> : <%= metafield.value %>
<% end %>
```

but I am getting error on app page. Is there anything else I need to add in code?

Comment: what is error??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Details would be highly appreciated. Try to add as much details as possible, e.g., stack trace of an error.

Comment: @bunty actually i want to show a text field for products and show this on product page, so how can i do this for shopify using ruby on rails?